# npm not respecting https://insteadof=git://

Tags: git, ssl, npm

when running npm install i get the following error

```
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (git://github.com/substack/esprima)
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (git@github.com:substack/esprima)
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:substack/esprima Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\ebic\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-s
ubstack-esprima-622885ba'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:substack/esprima ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:substack/esprima fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:substack/esprima
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:substack/esprima Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

However i am able to clone the repo manually with

```
git clone https://github.com/substack/esprima
```

the issue seems to be that npm when running git tries to fetch the dependencies with git@ or git://
I've therefore run the following

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

so my git config -l contains

```
url.https://.insteadof=git://
http.sslverify=false
url.https://github.com/.insteadof=git@github.com:
```

But get the same error above. Dependencies still being fetched with git@ or git://

Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here is the fill package.json

```
{
  "name": "corewebreact",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "repository": "",
  "private": true,
  "src": "src",
  "test": "test",
  "dist": "dist",
  "mainInput": "main",
  "mainOutput": "main",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~0.11.2",
    "react-router": "^0.7.0",
    "react-slider": "^0.1.2",
    "react-typeahead": "^1.0.0",
    "remove": "^0.1.5",
    "sugar": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "6to5": "^1.10.10",
    "6to5-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "chai": "^1.9.2",
    "colors": "^1.0.3",
    "connect-redis": "~2.1.0",
    "css-loader": "~0.9.0",
    "es6-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "express": "^4.9.8",
    "express-session": "~1.9.1",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-6to5": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-debug-task": "^0.1.5",
    "grunt-express-server": "^0.4.19",
    "grunt-istanbul-coverage": "^0.1.0",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.8.3",
    "grunt-mocha": "^0.4.11",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.12.2",
    "grunt-notify": "^0.4.1",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.3",
    "grunt-preprocess": "^4.0.0",
    "grunt-react": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-webpack": "~1.0.8",
    "http-proxy": "~1.5.3",
    "http-proxy-nocrash": "~0.1.2",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "inject-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "istanbul": "^0.3.2",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "jest": "^0.1.37",
    "jshint-loader": "~0.8.0",
    "jsx-loader": "~0.11.0",
    "karma": "~0.12.21",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.1.9",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-webpack": "~1.2.2",
    "less": "^1.7.5",
    "less-loader": "^0.7.7",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.6.0",
    "mocha": "^2.0.1",
    "mocha-istanbul": "^0.2.0",
    "module": "0.0.1",
    "morgan": "^1.4.0",
    "q": "~1.0.1",
    "random-words": "0.0.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "react-test-utils": "0.0.1",
    "redis": "^0.12.1",
    "request": "~2.47.0",
    "rewire": "^2.1.3",
    "rewire-webpack": "^1.0.0",
    "should": "^4.2.1",
    "sinon": "^1.11.1",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.6.0",
    "style-loader": "~0.8.0",
    "sweetjs-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.7.0",
    "url-loader": "~0.5.5",
    "webpack": "^1.4.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~1.6.5",
    "ws": "~0.4.32"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your package.json (or the full npm command if there is no package.json)?

Comment: Hi Doug, i added it to the main question.